# django-filter Filter based on year of a database column

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a column (dob) as date in the database. How do I filter on the year of it?

```
class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields =  ['first_name','last_name','dob',]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer there:
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#declaring-filters

```
class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    dob_year = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='dob', lookup_expr='year')

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields =  ['first_name','last_name','dob',]
```